# Delegation Issue with Power BI integration with Power Apps

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerapps

I create a Power BI with integration to power apps, I have around 26k data. I am using below code to capture data.

Filter(SP List, column = first(PowerBIIntegration.Data).Column)

My issue is that, it is not showing result on some of the data & I am suspecting delegation issue here. Has anyone experienced the same and what alternative work around has been done?

By the way, I am using filter in Power BI so i am expecting to show data based on my PBIx filter.

Comment: Is your Column set as an Index in SP?

Comment: Hi Sam, seems not. if i set it as an index will it solve it or i need to make work around with my indexed column?

Comment: If you set it as an index then it should work. Note that PowerApps at most can only pull 2,000 items. With the index set, it will return the first 2k where that column = x.